# Wordpress Elementor website excessive database connection when go live

Tags: wordpress, elementor, aws-aurora-serverless

I have been facing a strange issue with a WordPress website (Elementor builder).

We hosted multiple Wordpress websites on Aurora database.

2 sites are behaving strangely.

We develop the sites in a subdomain and when go live we just rename the subdomain to actual domain and make the necessary changes in the database.

But, for the aforementioned sites, whenever we launch the sites, we get a lots of database connections (show full processlist command) and Aurora database server go down.

When we change the domain name to some other domain, it works fine. When we disable the Elementor builder's header template, it works fine.

On subdomain it does not cause any issue. Query monitor do not show any suspicious queries. and "show full processlist" show 1000+ queries in either "sleep" or "cleaning up" or "cleaned up" state but do not kill them.

We also tried by disabling the Yoast plugin.

If you could throw some insight then it would be really helpful for us in troubleshooting the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: is it possible that you're getting a huge amount of concurrent connections on primary domain?

Comment: No. All the other sites are working fine. AWS hosting Setup includes 2 load balancers, Aurora database and EFS common file system.